# Javascript onoff button not working in chatbot

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, chatbot

I'm totally new in Javascript and i would like to build a chatbot using voice recognition and text to speech for a website. I made onoff button but it's not working.

I have tried:

```
while (value == "on") { 
  utterance.volume = 1; 
}
```

also

```
if (value == "on") {
  utterance.volume = 1;
} else {
  utterance.volume = 0;
}
```

but still there is something wrong. Any help

```
function onoff(){
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if(currentvalue == "on"){
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="on";
    }else{
          document.getElementById("onoff").value="off";
    }
 return currentvalue;
}



function speak(string){
var soundonoff = onoff();
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) 
    {return voice.name == "Alex";})[0];
    utterance.text = string;
    utterance.lang = "en-US"; 
    if (soundonoff == "on"){
    utterance.volume = 1; //0-1 interval
    }else{
    terance.volume = 0;
    }
    utterance.rate = 0.8;
    utterance.pitch = 1; //0-2 interval
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this there is pause and resume method for  window.speechSynthesis;

To stop :

```
speechSynthesis.pause(); // pauses utterances being spoken
```

see : [pause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/pause)

To Resume :

```
  speechSynthesis.resume();  /// resumes utters ,
```

see [resume](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/resume)

to Cancel (stop)

```
speechSynthesisInstance.cancel();
```

see [cancel](http://speechSynthesisInstance.cancel();)

according to your conditions, you can call these methods

for other methods see  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

**UPDATE:**  -

this is rough code, change according to your requirements

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="onoff" name="onoff" >On/Off<br>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="start" onclick="speak();" value ="start" > On/Off
 <br>
```

Script :

```
 <script>

  var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

   function speak(){
      var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('My pleasure, poke me up if you need more info.'); // 
      synth.speak(utterThis);
    }


 //// on check box change event call this 

   $('#onoff').change(function() {

      if($("#onoff").prop('checked') == true){
       speechSynthesis.pause();
      /// now I dont know you want to pause or stop, change it according to you 
       ///requirment 
       }  
     else {
         speechSynthesis.pause();
       }
  });
  </script>
```

***GITHUB*** - [sample project](https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is actually not in how to stop or pause the  speechSynthesis the problem is the button is not connected to the onclick event because whenever the button has value "on" in beginning, it stays on and whenever it has off it stays off. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: oh thanks, i'm working on this site:
https://codeshare.io/5QLrjw 
here you can find the whole code for the chatbot page
I couldn't share it here because it's longer than 200 letter

Comment: @WaelAlMasri I didn't get your code what you want to do, but I have updated my answer with a simple example, on checkbox change event, hope you will get some idea from that(accept as answer if it solves your problem)

Comment: i'm really thankful, but even in your code, it keeps speaking if you checked the box or not maybe it's the browser?
So what i wanna do is i want a mute button in case the user doesn't wanna hear anything so he can mute the chatbot but as i notices that when page load the button take one value and never change no matter how much you check

Comment: @WaelAlMasri  if checkbox is not working, then try on button click , case I have tried the same example, it was working for me, see have you added jquery library, see console for errors

Comment: also added sample project link to answer , see updated answer

Comment: Thank you man, i have found the solution i added a separate function for every state and it worked

Comment: @WaelAlMasri thats what I  was saying, dont you think